# Different noise on every object that are in array

Tags: animation

So i have a scene where i want to have a lot of flickering lights, and i've wanted them just like in Stranger Things where every light is flickering on it's own (One neon flickers faster and the other one slower for example) But if i do an array and add a noise every things flickers in the same pattern

Example:
https://i.imgur.com/M4B0Hxd.gif

I've defeated this problem with just copying and pasting ceiling tiles with Shift + D but this made this very inefficient and there were a lot of gaps

[image]

And this gave me the effect i've really wanted:

https://i.imgur.com/YFPobZa.gif

Is there any way of speeding this up?

Also, i've noticed when adding noise modifier it's always the same so i need to change the offset so that it can be different from each other.

Comment: Please post images inside your question instead of external links.

Answer (score 2):

Just use UV texture coordinates for the noise, and offset UVs for the Array modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the *Array*, unwrap with the *Project from View* option, scale down the UVs with *Individual Origins* on:

[image]

Then use a *Noise Texture* before your *Emission*:

[image]

Move the texture to switch on and off the lights, it will look random:

[image]